# run docker nginx container and be able to execute commands

Tags: docker, nginx

i try to tests features with docker,
and i am asking why i can not interact with nginx contenair
it is launched ?

```
docker run -ti nginx
```

What is the way to run the nginx docker AND be able to launch commands into the contenair ?

Comment: What leads to the "launch commands" requirement?  A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process, and you wouldn't normally "launch commands" inside a standalone Nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `command`

```
docker run -it nginx bash
```

This `command` will run a container from the `nginx` image, and access inside that container.

Comment: thanks it works. BUT, it does not start web server as if i do not write keyword bash at the end of command (e.g. "docker run -it nginx"). Why ?